# How to fit button squared border to image rounded border

Tags: java, css, javafx

Hi I've tried to make rounded button with round photo inside but border is still a square which made button clickable outside of a image[image: this is how it looks like for now]

There is my css code

```css
#button{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-background-image: url("utils/SmileyFace.png");
    -fx-border-radius: 25px;

}
```

I would like to eliminate all button parts that are outside of a image

Comment: `BackgroundImage` does not contain a property for rounded corners. The only way to do this would be setting the `clip` property (from java code only) or setting the `shape` property (possible from CSS but requires knowlege about the image size).

Comment: yes i thought about it even when i'm aplying fx-shape which is` M 100 400 A 50 50 0 1 1 250 250 A 50 50 0 1 1 100 400` for that image and border is still a square

Comment: That does not seem right. A rect with rounded corners should have 8 parts. Furthermore a shape should be closed. E.g. using the following path for a node of size `500 x 400` yields rounded corners with radius 20 for me: `M0 20A20 20 0 0 1 20 0H480A20 20 0 0 1 500 20V380A20 20 0 0 1 480 400H20A20 20 0 0 1 0 380Z`

Comment: Hmm thats quite strange ive used some kind of online generator for that shape could you please check for me what its should be for 250px 250px Square?

Comment: Not too hard to do this yourself. Just replace the 20s with your radius and the other non-0/1 values with `size-radius` where `size` is either the height or the width.